# Porting Spring applications to Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm pretty new to Spring Boot but I have been developing Spring applications. Pardon the silly question but I wanted to know if Spring applications are fully portable to Spring Boot- obviously changing pom.xml dependencies, but with no change in Java code or XML files.
In short, is there any known issue when moving to Spring Boot?
Thanks!

Comment: refer https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-migration

Comment: One of the benefits of Spring Boot is that you don't _want_ to port XML files. You would want to rely on auto configuration.

Comment: If by **fully portable** you mean get the same results, yes they are fully portable. But apart from the dependencies, you should probably also change your configuration files to configuration classes, remove some of them to rely on convention and auto-configuration. It's gonna be a tedious job, anyway.